# xUnit: [Theory] и ни одного [Fact]: как же он работает?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, xunit

С тестами я сильно "на вы", то есть прочитал строго Getting started.

И когда написано "как в учебнике" - то есть, вот тебе [Theory], а вот несколько [Fact] - и это отдельные тесты, которые запустятся - то я всё понимаю.

А здесь я встретился с *рабочим* тестом, в котором написано сверху [Theory], но ни одного [Fact] нету, и это как то работает. Ну, то есть, первой же своей правкой кода я его сломал.

Начинается тест с атрибутов

```
    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(TestCases))]
```

Как я понимаю, это то, что называется "параметризованный тест"?

Как же это выполняется? Может, есть какой то пример или отдельная статья, которая бы давала общее представление о том, как писать такие "не прямые" тесты?

Я не могу привести код, так как код из закрытого репозитория, а сделать отдельный проект, чтобы воспроизвести проблему, я еще не могу - слишком много непонятного в основном проекте.

Comment: А почему ты считаешь что теория( тест с набором проверяемых атрибутов) вообще должна зависеть от тестов-фактов(тест без набора атрибутов)? Я вот незнаком с XUnit-ом в принципе - но судя по первой же статье в интернете https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/ не вижу между ними прямой связи. Это 2 независимых один от второго модификатора

Comment: @Andrew - Для меня новой явилась концепция параметризованных тестов. Поэтому я и написал вопрос в такой форме. Спасибо за ссылку на статью!

Comment: Тогда, наверняка, необходимо в принципе разобраться какой модификатор что значит, а не бездумно их использовать не понимая их значений :) Найди какую-то книгу в интернете по XUnit-у или хотя бы Cheat-Sheet и начинай с этого :)